# Refactor the foreach loop with continue in it?

Tags: c#, refactoring

I was trying to refactor a very long `foreach` loop. I got stuck as at few places I am having `continue` in it. Here is some dummy code to mimic my original code

```
IEnumerable<dynamic> allData = FetchAllData();
IEnumerable<dynamic> relativeData = FetchAllRelativData();

foreach (var rdata in relativeData)
{
    IEnumerable<dynamic> dataTobeProcessed = allData.Where(c => c.Name = rdata.Name);

    //Do something

    //if then Continue

    // do something

    //if then continue

    // do something

    // do something

    // add data to db
}
```

Here I have remove all the do something part in to separate function. But again I am having few code portion having `continue` in it, that is breaking loop and moving forward to next element. So, I was unable to separate that part.

Again, here I am having constraint like steps are in continuation. Means first thing happens then second one and then third one then next... So, I can't move the position of code as of now. Because of that my function got big, around 300 lines and it is now getting hard to change or maintain.

Please provide a good solution for removing `continue` or another way to `break` method by changing the way of coding.

Please let me know if any other details are needed.

Comment: can you post the whole method? I know 300 lines is long but maybe that helps more then an example in comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just refactor the if blocks into separate functions with appropriate names.
Then put all the ifs inside eachother instead of the continue.

```
if (!something) 
{
  DoFirstThing();
  if (!otherthing)
  {
     DoSechondThing();
  }
} 
//continue implicitly happens here anyway.
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly I should move every other things then if and continue right?

Answer (score 2):

At the start of the loop, set a boolean - let's call it `escape` to false..  Now replace all of your existing `continue`s with an assignment of `escape` to true.  This, by itself, isn't a true refactoring - it changes the behavior of the existing code - but we are only partway done.  Now select the body of the loop (now with no `continue`s), and extract it as a method.  In the extracted method, replace each assignment of `escape` with a `return` statement.  Eliminate the original creation of the `escape` variable, and your code is in a state that is easier to further refactor.

Answer (score 0):

You dont mention whether the if implementation of your DoSomething() calls share args and return types, *if* they do, an alternative option would be to create a collection of Funcs containing your DoSomething() logic, and instead of lots of if statements you could just loop over the Func implementations until the return value dictates you should break.

```
var somethingFuncs = new List<Func<x, bool>> 
{
  DoSomething,
  DoSomethingB,
  Blah....
};

foreach(var something in somethingFuncs)
{
  var result = something(arg);

  if (result)
  {
    break;
  } 
}
```